# How do you terminate resources that are older than x days using aws-nuke?

Tags: yaml, aws-nuke

I am using aws-nuke to prune resources in our sandbox account. I would like to only delete resources that are more than 7 days old.

I have tried the following

```
accounts:
  ************:
    filters:
      EC2Instance:
      - property: dateOlderThan
        value: "time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, -7)"
```

I have also tried subtracting one day.

```
accounts:
  ************:
    filters:
      EC2Instance:
      - property: dateOlderThan
        value: "time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, -1)"
```

I have also tried subtracting 27 years.

```
accounts:
  ************:
    filters:
      EC2Instance:
      - property: dateOlderThan
        value: "time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, -10000)"
```

All return the same results,

> Scan complete: *x* total, *x* nukeable, 0 filtered.

This suggests that the date calculation is being ignored.

How do I give it the current date minus 7 days?

Comment: I see there is a close vote - please let me know how I can improve the question to ameliorate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [aws-nuke#756](https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke/issues/756), you can either,

- specify the date in hours: `168h`
- specify `-7d`